# Gatttool Non-Interactive mode, multiple char-write-req

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, gatttool

I would like to retrieve the data of a stryd footpod. I would like to listen to 2 separate uuid's. In interactive mode, I would connect using

```
sudo gatttool -t random -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -I
connect
char-write-req 0x001a 0100
char-write-req 0x000f 0100
```

However, as I use this as part of a perl script, I would like to leverage non-interactive mode.

Starting gatttool with a single handle works fine:

```
gatttool -t random -i hci0 -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --char-write-req --handle=0x001a  --value=0100 --listen
```

However how do I pass both handles at the same time? Following does not work.

```
gatttool -t random -i hci0 -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --char-write-req --handle=0x001a  --value=0100 --char-write-req --handle=0x000f  --value=0100 --listen
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution on http://www.humbug.in/2014/using-gatttool-manualnon-interactive-mode-read-ble-devices/

```
gatttool -t random -i hci0 -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --char-write-req --handle=0x001a  --value=0100; sleep 1; gatttool -t random -i hci0 -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --char-write-req --handle=0x000f  --value=0100 --listen
```

Does the trick!